# Listview not clicked in android

Tags: android, json

Please help me this is my activity code where i set adapter in listview.i want to click in list view but not clicked so please help me to find out this problem.thanks in advance. this is important section in my project.

```
public class Teacher Locator extends ActionBarActivity {

    Defaultlistadapter defaultlistadapter;  
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);      
        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_company);

        //This is asyktask class
        new DefaultListService().execute();
    }

    //Defaultlist service  class
    private class DefaultListService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
            ServiceHandler2 sh=new ServiceHandler2();
            String url_defaultlist ="http://192.168.0.11/highschoolcoopsapp/?tag=allcompanyprofiles";
            String strjson=sh.makeServiceCall(url_defaultlist, ServiceHandler2.GET);
            Log.v("ResponseDefault",strjson);
            if(strjson!=null)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject jobjsearch=new JSONObject(strjson);
                    tag_list=jobjsearch.getString("tag");
                    success_list=jobjsearch.getString("success");
                    error_list=jobjsearch.getString("error");

                    Log.v("TagSearch",tag_list);
                    Log.v("SuccessSearch",success_list);
                    Log.v("ErrorSearch",error_list);
                    //JsonArray Working
                    JSONArray jarr_list =jobjsearch.getJSONArray("searchresult");
                    for (int i=0; i<jarr_list.length(); i++) {  
                        JSONObject obbj=jarr_list.getJSONObject(i);
                        name_list = obbj.getString("name");
                        arrname_list.add(name_list);
                        Log.v("Companyname",name_list);
                        // allNames.add(name);
                        address_list = obbj.getString("address");
                        arraddress_list.add(address_list);    
                        Log.v("Companyaddress",address_list);
                        city_list = obbj.getString("city");
                        arrcity_list.add(city_list);
                        Log.v("Companycity",city_list);
                        state_list = obbj.getString("state");
                        arrstate_list.add(state_list);
                        Log.v("Companystate",state_list);
                        country_list = obbj.getString("country");
                        arrcountry_list.add(country_list);
                        Log.v("Companycountry",country_list);

                        //categorytitle
                        categoryid_list=obbj.getString("title");
                        arrcategoryid_list.add(categoryid_list);
                        Log.v("category",categoryid_list);
                        //title_list=obbj.getString("title");
                        //arrtitle_list.add(title_list);
                        intro_list=obbj.getString("intro");
                        arrintro_list.add(intro_list);

                        ///categoryid
                        str_categoryid=obbj.getString("category_id");
                        arrcategryid_list.add(str_categoryid);

                        //Id
                        str_id=obbj.getString("id");
                        arrid_list.add(str_id);    
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");  
            }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                defaultlistadapter=new Defaultlistadapter(TeacherLocator.this, arrname_list, arraddress_list, arrcity_list, arrstate_list,              arrcountry_list,arrcategoryid_list,arrintro_list);      
            defaultlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listview.setAdapter(defaultlistadapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(TeacherLocator.this," Not clicked....................", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(TeacherLocator.this,"Listview :"+str_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } 
}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class Defaultlistadapter extends BaseAdapter{    
    String val,valtag,tag_list,success_list,error_list;
    ListView listview,listview2;

    public Defaultlistadapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> arrname_list,
            ArrayList<String> arraddress_list, ArrayList<String> arrcity_list, ArrayList<String> arrstate_list, ArrayList<String> arrcountry_list, ArrayList<String> arrcategoryid_list,ArrayList<String>arrayintro_list) {

        mcontext=c;
        this.arrayname_list=arrname_list;
        this.arrayaddress_list=arraddress_list;
        this.arraycity_list=arrcity_list;
        this.arraystate_list=arrstate_list;
        this.arraycountry_list=arrcountry_list;
        this.arraycategoryid_list=arrcategoryid_list;
        this.arrayintro_list=arrayintro_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {    
        return arrayname_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder hd=null;
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.defaultlist, null);   
            hd=new Holder();
            hd.txt_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_list);
            hd.txt_address= TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address_list);
            hd.txt_city=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_city_list);
            hd.txt_state=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_state_list);
            hd.txt_country=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_country);
            hd.txt_categoryid=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_category_list);
            hd.txt_intro=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_intro_list);
            hd.web_intro=(WebView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.web_intro);

            convertView.setTag(hd);    
        }
        else{
            hd=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        hd.txt_name.setText(arrayname_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_address.setText(arrayaddress_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_city.setText(arraycity_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_state.setText(arraystate_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_country.setText(arraycountry_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_categoryid.setText(arraycategoryid_list.get(position));
        hd.txt_intro.setText(arrayintro_list.get(position));
        websetting=hd.web_intro.getSettings();
        hd.web_intro.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
        hd.web_intro.loadData(String.format(htmlText, arrayintro_list.get(position)), "text/html", "utf-8");

        return convertView;
    }

    public class Holder{
        TextView txt_name,txt_address,txt_city,txt_state,txt_country,txt_categoryid,txt_intro;
        WebView web_intro;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a Toast "Not clicked" inside Click listener?

Comment: Seriously who give so many extra lines in the code. Almost left editing half way... Sigh...

Comment: can u your xml where your listview  is?

Comment: Why you are creating new adapter on every response? ItemClickListener and setAdapter are not supposed to set again and again

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this happens when items in listview are focusable so Try to add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the layout of your custom adaptor row layout i.e i your case your R.layout.defaultlist should be like this :

```
<LinearLayout <--your xml's parent layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" > <<-- add this line of code
```

May it will help you.

Answer (score -2):

What about if you set the click for the `convertView` inside the `getView` function?

Comment: Please ask for clarifications in comment.

Comment: convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
   });

Comment: but i want to get lisview position in click of litview item

Comment: You have the position in the `getView` function: `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) ...`